# Jython on Ubuntu 18.04, installation location

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I ran the following to install Jython:

```
sudo apt-get install jython
```

What installed is version 2.7.1:

```
$ which jython
/usr/bin/jython
$ jython --version
Jython 2.7.1
```

However, then I ran into [this bug](http://bugs.jython.org/issue2683) (also [reported as this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jython/+bug/1771476)) and wanted to manually install Jython instead, to try a different version.

Current latest from [Jython.org](http://www.jython.org/downloads.html) is 2.7.0, although I would also try 2.5.3 if that failed.

I ran

```
sudo java -jar jython-installer-2.7.0.jar
```

And installed to `/usr/local/lib/jython2.7.0/` and symlinked

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/jython2.7.0/bin/jython /usr/local/bin/jython
```

So now I have:

```
$ which jython
/usr/local/bin/jython
$ jython --version
Jython 2.7.1
```

And the same bug. OK, so let's remove the Ubuntu installed Jython. Maybe there's a library mix-up (or maybe verison 2.7.0 **IS** version 2.7.1 ?)

```
$ sudo apt-get remove jython
$ which jython
/usr/local/bin/jython
$ jython --version
bash: /usr/bin/jython: No such file or directory
$ ll /usr/local/bin/jython
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Jul 29 07:44 /usr/local/bin/jython -> /usr/local/lib/jython2.7.0/bin/jython*
```

And now I'm confused.

Why does `which jython` point to `/usr/local/bin/` but when I try to run jython, it's looking in `/usr/bin/` ?

Answer (score 2):

Bash [caches paths](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables) to executables. `which` doesn't know about this cache; it follows the logic that you as an end-user expect. I would assume the problem resolved on starting a new shell.

Jython 2.7.0 and 2.7.1 are distinct versions. After you installed 2.7.0, you symlinked it to a location that probably comes *after* `/usr/bin/` in your `PATH`*, causing it to continue to prefer the system version.

*`PATH` is an environment variable that tells the shell where to look, and in what order, when you type a command. You can view it, like any environment variables, with `echo $PATH`.